# Monitoring process start, exit OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im (trying to) create an app that's monitoring process start and exit.

Info I would like to get is proc creation time, PID, and path.
Only issue is that I can't find the "correct" way to do this.
Been googling like made, the last couple of days. 
I hope this can be done in user space...
So question is: Is kqueue an option?
Or is there a better option? Like on Linux, I can get proc events via linux/netlink.h.

Thanks

Comment: If the target process is a GUI application, this is quite easy; you can just use `NSRunningApplication`, either via its `init?(processIdentifier:)` initializer or via `NSWorkspace`'s `runningApplications` property.

Comment: If you need to get the info for any process, that will not be as easy. I'd expect that the source code for the `/bin/ps` tool should help, though: https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-172/ps/

Comment: Are you trying to monitor a specific known process? Do you already have the PID of the process? Are you trying to monitor *all* processes?

Comment: No. Im trying to find the best and most efficient way to monitor, process start (spawn, fork exec) and exit on OS X. in c... without having to code a kernel extension.

Answer (score 0):

Neither will do, sorry.
NSRunningApps doesn't provide me with the BSD Proc's, And both suggestions, doesn't handle newly created processes, but return a list of all running apps / proc.
Ive looked at NSNotificationCenter, but that leaves me with the same issue as NSRunningApps...

Comment: Use the comments ("add a comment") to reply to someone. Don't add an answer.